# Adding a JPanel to JFrame through an anonymous action listener class

Tags: java, swing

I've created an anonymous Action Listener class that when an action is fired, the listener creates a JPanel with 5 JTextFields for the user to input information.

The code runs without compiler errors, the problem is the JPanel that is created by the Action Listener is not showing on the GUI.

Anonymous Action Listener code:

```
private class addListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
        GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(5,2);
        addPanel.setLayout(gl);

        JLabel genreLabel = new JLabel("Genre: ");
        JTextField txbGenre = new JTextField();
        addPanel.add(genreLabel);
        addPanel.add(txbGenre);

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title: ");
        JTextField txbTitle = new JTextField();
        addPanel.add(titleLabel);
        addPanel.add(txbTitle);

        JLabel ratingLabel = new JLabel("Rating: ");
        JTextField txbRating = new JTextField();
        addPanel.add(ratingLabel);
        addPanel.add(txbRating);

        JLabel directorLabel = new JLabel("Director: ");
        JTextField txbDirector = new JTextField();
        addPanel.add(directorLabel);
        addPanel.add(txbDirector);

        JLabel castLabel = new JLabel("Cast: ");
        JTextField txbCast = new JTextField();
        addPanel.add(castLabel);
        addPanel.add(txbCast);

        addPanel.setVisible(true);
        MovieListPanel.this.add(addPanel);

    }
}
```

Constructor for JFrame:

```
public MovieListPanel()
{
    super("Movie Database");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JMenu movieMenu = new JMenu("Movie menu options");

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    //Sub Menu creation
    JMenu searchMenu = new JMenu("Search for a movie");

    JMenuItem titleChoice = new JMenuItem("By title: ");
    titleChoice.addActionListener(new titleListener());
    searchMenu.add(titleChoice);

    JMenuItem ratingChoice = new JMenuItem("By rating: ");
    ratingChoice.addActionListener(new ratingListener());
    searchMenu.add(ratingChoice);

    JMenuItem genreChoice = new JMenuItem("By genre: ");
    genreChoice.addActionListener(new genreListener());
    searchMenu.add(genreChoice);

    JMenuItem castChoice = new JMenuItem("By cast: ");
    castChoice.addActionListener(new castListener());
    searchMenu.add(castChoice);

    JMenuItem directorChoice = new JMenuItem("By director: ");
    directorChoice.addActionListener(new directorListener());
    searchMenu.add(directorChoice);

    JMenuItem multiChoice = new JMenuItem("By cast/year/rating:");
    multiChoice.addActionListener(new multiSearchListener());
    searchMenu.add(multiChoice);

    movieMenu.add(searchMenu);
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //Main menu choices creation
    JMenuItem addChoice = new JMenuItem("Add a Movie");
    addChoice.addActionListener(new addListener());
    movieMenu.add(addChoice);

    JMenuItem removeChoice = new JMenuItem("Remove a movie");
    removeChoice.addActionListener(new removeListener());
    movieMenu.add(removeChoice);

    JMenuItem displayChoice = new JMenuItem("Display all movies");
    displayChoice.addActionListener(new displayListener());
    movieMenu.add(displayChoice);

    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    bar.add(movieMenu);
    setJMenuBar(bar);


}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

Updated code:

Private ActionListener class which extends JPanel

```
private class addListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
        GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(5,2);
        addPanel.setLayout(gl);

        JLabel genreLabel = new JLabel("Genre: ");
        JTextField txbGenre = new JTextField();
        addPanel.add(genreLabel);
        addPanel.add(txbGenre);

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title: ");
        JTextField txbTitle = new JTextField();
        addPanel.add(titleLabel);
        addPanel.add(txbTitle);

        JLabel ratingLabel = new JLabel("Rating: ");
        JTextField txbRating = new JTextField();
        addPanel.add(ratingLabel);
        addPanel.add(txbRating);

        JLabel directorLabel = new JLabel("Director: ");
        JTextField txbDirector = new JTextField();
        addPanel.add(directorLabel);
        addPanel.add(txbDirector);

        JLabel castLabel = new JLabel("Cast: ");
        JTextField txbCast = new JTextField();
        addPanel.add(castLabel);
        addPanel.add(txbCast);


        addPanel.setVisible(true);
        add(addPanel);
        addPanel.revalidate();
        addPanel.repaint();

    }
}
```

JFrame class

```
public class MovieApp extends JFrame{

private MovieListPanel view = new MovieListPanel();

public MovieApp() 
{
    super("Movie Database");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JMenu movieMenu = new JMenu("Movie menu options");

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    //Sub Menu creation
    JMenu searchMenu = new JMenu("Search for a movie");

    JMenuItem titleChoice = new JMenuItem("By title: ");
    titleChoice.addActionListener(new titleListener());
    searchMenu.add(titleChoice);

    JMenuItem ratingChoice = new JMenuItem("By rating: ");
    ratingChoice.addActionListener(new ratingListener());
    searchMenu.add(ratingChoice);

    JMenuItem genreChoice = new JMenuItem("By genre: ");
    genreChoice.addActionListener(new genreListener());
    searchMenu.add(genreChoice);

    JMenuItem castChoice = new JMenuItem("By cast: ");
    castChoice.addActionListener(new castListener());
    searchMenu.add(castChoice);

    JMenuItem directorChoice = new JMenuItem("By director: ");
    directorChoice.addActionListener(new directorListener());
    searchMenu.add(directorChoice);

    JMenuItem multiChoice = new JMenuItem("By cast/year/rating:");
    multiChoice.addActionListener(new multiSearchListener());
    searchMenu.add(multiChoice);

    movieMenu.add(searchMenu);
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //Main menu choices creation
    JMenuItem addChoice = new JMenuItem("Add a Movie");
    addChoice.addActionListener(new addListener());
    movieMenu.add(addChoice);

    JMenuItem removeChoice = new JMenuItem("Remove a movie");
    removeChoice.addActionListener(new removeListener());
    movieMenu.add(removeChoice);

    JMenuItem displayChoice = new JMenuItem("Display all movies");
    displayChoice.addActionListener(new displayListener());
    movieMenu.add(displayChoice);

    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    bar.add(movieMenu);
    setJMenuBar(bar);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add (or remove) components from a visible GUI the basic logic is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

By default all component has a size of (0, 0) so you need the revalidate() to invoke the layout manager which will give each component a size/location based on the rules of the layout manager.

Comment: Thanks camickr, I will try this when I get home.

Comment: I have now added both revalidate and repaint into the code, doing this however did not change the outcome, the GUI still does not show the JPanels. I've included the details of the code with the update, do you think i've made a mistake somewhere else? (not in the two classes shown).

Comment: `I have now added both revalidate and repaint into the code,` - that is not what I suggested. Look at my code structure. You need to add the child components to the panel `BEFORE` you revalidate the panel. How can the layout manager give a size to a component if it hasn't even been added to the panel yet???

Comment: I had the mistake of extending both classes with JFrame, this has now been changed to include extension of JFrame and JPanel. Is it possible for  the private class ActionListeners to be added as an actionlistener inside the JMenu creation?